# HTTP Error 403: SSL is required on trying to install gevent-psycopg2 with pip

Tags: python, pip, psycopg2, gevent

While trying to install gevent-psycopg2 using pip On linux
Using this command:

```
pip install gevent-psycopg2
```

I got this error

```
Collecting gevent-psycopg2
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/72/11/aa122be6a3bdbc7d16752c5e6771b362ca7ebaef0f52113e036062dd2c12/gevent-psycopg2-0.0.3.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Downloading http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/d/distribute/distribute-0.6.24.tar.gz
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "", line 1, in 
      File "/tmp/pip-install-q1DRBs/gevent-psycopg2/setup.py", line 5, in 
        use_setuptools()
      File "distribute_setup.py", line 145, in use_setuptools
        return _do_download(version, download_base, to_dir, download_delay)
      File "distribute_setup.py", line 124, in _do_download
        to_dir, download_delay)
      File "distribute_setup.py", line 193, in download_setuptools
        src = urlopen(url)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 154, in urlopen
        return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 435, in open
        response = meth(req, response)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 548, in http_response
        'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 473, in error
        return self._call_chain(*args)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 407, in _call_chain
        result = func(*args)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 556, in http_error_default
        raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
    urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: SSL is required

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-q1DRBs/gevent-psycopg2/
```

- I already upgraded pip to 19.0.3 , and my python version is 2.7.12+
- I tried to download the archive from git and to install it using setup.py but i end up with a similar error.
- I also already tried to install using git with

```
pip install git+git:https://github.com/zacharyvoase/gevent-psycopg2
```

I dont know what i'm missing? 
Or is there another way to install from source?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The project](https://pypi.org/project/gevent-psycopg2/) seems to be at the early stage of development (version 0.0.3) but already abandoned (last release in 2012). The installation code [uses `distribute`](https://github.com/zacharyvoase/gevent-psycopg2/blob/2cc79ec33915e2ba13224923424b60531f87db55/distribute_setup.py#L50) which it tries to download from http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/d/distribute/; even if the code succeeded connecting to the site it would receive error 404.

At [the git repository](https://github.com/zacharyvoase/gevent-psycopg2) there is the hint: "Obsolete; use https://bitbucket.org/dvarrazzo/psycogreen/ instead." [The named package](https://pypi.org/project/psycogreen/) seems to be much more elaborated (version 1.0.1) and fresh (Dec 2018). So start with

```
pip install psycogreen
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  Yes i am aware that it is and old project but it is used in a module(that i would like to test and use) of an app i use in prod .it would be a lot of work to replace every usage with psycogreen in source code. If i edit the distribute url, replacing http with https , could it work ?

Comment: Nop. I said: *The installation code uses distribute which it tries to download from http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/d/distribute/; even if the code succeeded connecting to the site it would receive error 404.*